# VC++ Error LNK2005 Already Defined In

Tags: c++, visual-c++, include, linker-errors

Hi I'm currently working on a program in C++ and my IDE is obviously VC++ and I came across this linker error.

```
error LNK2005: "class Graphics TheGraphics" (?TheGraphics@@3VGraphics@@A) already defined in Game.obj
```

I looked up how to fix it but none of the links got it fixed. So I thought I ask you all myself.
These are all my files

```
Game.h
Graphics.h
Inc.h
Main.h

Game.cpp
Graphics.cpp
Main.cpp
WndProc.cpp
```

and in all of the header files I have the

```
#ifndef ...
#define...
..
#endif
```

and I also have some includes in the header files.

in Inc.h I have this between the #ifndef and #define

```
#include <Windows.h>
#include <d3d9.h>
#include <d3dx9.h>

#include "Game.h"
#include "Graphics.h"
```

in Main.h I have this between the #ifndef and #define

```
#include "Inc.h"
```

and I've also created to objects Game and Graphics objects

```
extern Game TheGame;
extern Graphics TheGraphics
```

I've also declared 1 function

```
LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc(HWND hWnd,
                         UINT Msg,
                         WPARAM wParam,
                         LPARAM lParam);
```

That's Main.h

In Game.h and Graphics.h I have this before the #ifndef and #define

```
#include "Main.h"
```

and in Game.h I have made a class called Game and a enum called GAMESTATE.
In Graphics.h I have made a class called Graphics.

All the .cpp files for the class only include their class header and WndProc includes Main.h

and after all that I get this when I compile.

```
1>Graphics.obj : error LNK2005: "class Graphics TheGraphics" (?TheGraphics@@3VGraphics@@A) already defined in Game.obj
1>Graphics.obj : error LNK2005: "class Game TheGame" (?TheGame@@3VGame@@A) already defined in Game.obj
1>Main.obj : error LNK2005: "class Graphics TheGraphics" (?TheGraphics@@3VGraphics@@A) already defined in Game.obj
1>Main.obj : error LNK2005: "class Game TheGame" (?TheGame@@3VGame@@A) already defined in Game.obj
1>WndProc.obj : error LNK2005: "class Graphics TheGraphics" (?TheGraphics@@3VGraphics@@A) already defined in Game.obj
1>WndProc.obj : error LNK2005: "class Game TheGame" (?TheGame@@3VGame@@A) already defined in Game.obj
1>F:\Games\Zombie Lypse\Release\Zombie Lypse.exe : fatal error LNK1169: one or more multiply defined symbols found
```

please help I've looked everywhere and I've tried to fix it myself. Still nothing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have externed the globals everywhere but not defined it anywhere.

`extern` doesn't define variables. It just tells the compiler that the variable is defined elsewhere. So you have to actually define it elsewhere.

You can do this.

In the header file

```
/* main.h */

MYEXTERN Game TheGame;
MYEXTERN Graphics TheGraphics
```

In the first .c file

In main.cpp

```
/* MYEXTERN doesn't evaluate to anything, so var gets defined here */
#define MYEXTERN 
#include "main.h"
```

In the other .cpp files

```
/* MYEXTERN evaluates to extern, so var gets externed in all other CPP files */
#define MYEXTERN extern
#include "main.h"
```

So it gets defined in only one .cpp file & gets externed in all the others.

Comment: I have `extern Game TheGame` and `extern Graphics TheGraphics` in the `Main.h` and in `Main.cpp` I have `Game TheGame` and `Graphics TheGraphics` in Main.cpp isn't that how it's supposto be?